# Solve $(\sin \theta-2r\cos^2 \theta) dr+r(\sin \theta +\cos \theta)d\theta=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(\sin \theta-2r\cos^2 \theta) dr+r(\sin \theta +\cos \theta)d\theta=0$

Let We choose

$M=\sin \theta-2r\cos^2 \theta \implies \frac{\partial M}{\partial \theta}=\cos \theta+4r\sin \theta$

and

$N=r(\sin \theta +\cos \theta) \implies \frac{\partial N}{\partial r}=(\sin \theta +\cos \theta)$

hence this is not exact equation, How to convert this is into exact?

Comment: I bet that there is a typo : probably no $r$ in $M$. It would be already  not be a so easy problem.

Comment: There’s an error in your calculation of $\partial M/\partial \theta$. Remember the chain rule!